# How to differentiate a character and a number?

Tags: c, scanf, var

I have a variable `int number` and I need code that only allows introducing 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5 to the variable.

I have `scanf` and I just do an `if...else` to check out if the number is between 1 and 5, but the point is that I don't know what to do if I introduce a character, e.g. 'q'. I mean, I want the program to say "That's a character, not a number."

Comment: `scanf` would never parse a string as a number if that string is not parsable as a number. Check whether `scanf` succeeds and you'll be fine.

Comment: Is it me or has this question been asked about a million times over the last week?

Comment: @joe there are always loads of scanf questions.  IMHO people starting on C shouldn't be let near it for the first couple of months!

Comment: I'm sure I have seen the specific question "I have `scanf`ed a character how do I check if it's an integer". Maybe it's just normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use sscanf on a buffer (or in the example below, argv the program argument) to attempt to find a digit, then a character.
The return code from sscanf is :

> ```
>    ...the number of input items  successfully  matched
>    and assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero in the
>    event of an early matching failure.
> ```

Here is an example program

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv){

int val=-1;
char other;
int code;

if (argc !=2 ) {
    printf("please give an arg to program\n");
    exit(0);
}

code=sscanf(argv[1],"%d",&val);

if (code == 1) {
    printf( "number %d", val);
    }
    else {
        code=sscanf(argv[1],"%c",&other);
        if (code == 1) {
            printf("character is %c", other);
        }
        else {
            printf("error occured");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Only accept input of 1 to 5, inclusive:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int rc, answer = 0;

    printf("A number between 1 and 5: ");
    rc = scanf("%i", &answer);

    if(rc == EOF || rc == 0 || answer > 5 || answer <= 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Only numbers between 1 and 5, please.\n");
        return -99;
    } else {
        printf("You entered: %d\n", answer);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ## Return Value
>
> These functions return the number of input items successfully matched and assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero in the event of an early matching failure.
>
> The value EOF is returned if the end of input is reached before either the first successful conversion or a matching failure occurs. EOF is also returned if a read error occurs, in which case the error indicator for the stream (see ferror(3)) is set, and errno is set indicate the error.

Basically, `scanf` will continue to scan until a match is made or it fails.  An example program would be this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int number, result;

  result = scanf("%i", &number);

  if(result == EOF) {
    // an error occured.
    fprintf(stderr, "That's not a number");
  } else {
    // logic!  yay!
    // the result is in `number`.
  }
}
```

Use [`man scanf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int clearStdin()
{
    while (getchar() != '\n');

    return 1;
}

int main()  
{
    int integer = 0;
    char character;

    printf("Enter an integer not a character:\n");
    do
    {
        printf("? ");
    } while (((scanf("%d%c", &integer, &character) != 2) || (character != '\n')) && clearStdin());

    printf("You entered the following integer: %d\n", integer);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` will return the number of successful conversions and assignments, so you can check that to make sure you read at least 1 digit character:

```
int value;
...
if ( scanf( "%d", &value ) == 1 )
{
  // read at least 1 digit
}
else
{
  // first character was not whitespace or a digit
}
```

What's this "read at least 1 digit" nonsense?  The `%d` conversion specifier tells `scanf` to skip any leading whitespace, then read and convert decimal digits until it finds a non-digit character.  This means if you type a string like `"12w4"`, `scanf` will convert and assign `12` to `value`, return 1, and leave `"w4"` in the input stream to foul up the next read.

That's probably not the behavior you want.  You could scan for a following non-digit character, like so:

```
#include <ctype.h>
...
int value;
char follow;
...
if ( scanf( "%d%c", &value, &follow ) == 2 )
{
  if ( !isspace( follow ))
  {
    fprintf( stderr, "detected non-digit character in input\n" );
  }
}
else
{
  // first character was not whitespace or a digit
}
```

You've caught that case, but your input may now be in a bad state; how do you know if the next character was part of a bad input or not?  IOW, how do you know the input was `12w4` and not `12w 4`?

Personally, I take a different approach.  I read the input as a string, then use `strtol` to perform the conversion:

```
/**
 * Assuming a 64-bit integer value, average 3.2 bits per decimal digit, we  
 * need to store up to 22 digits plus an optional sign character plus the 0 
 * terminator
 */
define INPUT_SIZE 24
...
char input[INPUT_SIZE] = {0};
long value = 0;
...
if ( fgets( input, sizeof input, stdin ))
{
  char *newline = strchr( input, '\n' );
  if ( !newline )
  {
    fprintf( stderr, "Input is too long for a 64-bit integer...rejecting\n" );
    /**
     * Cycle through the input stream until we see the newline character
     */
    while ( fgets( input, sizeof input, stdin ) && !strchr( input, '\n' ))
      ;
  }
  else
  {
    char *chk; // will point to the first character that's *not* 
               // part of a decimal integer

    long temp = strtol( input, &chk, 10 );
    if ( !isspace( *chk ) && *chk != 0 )
    {
      fprintf( stderr, "%s is not a valid integer input\n", input );
    }
    else
    {
      value = temp;
    }
  }
}
```

This allows me to catch cases where the input value is obviously too long to store in the target data type, something from which `scanf` does *not* protect you.  It also allows me to catch cases where a non-digit character is fat-fingered in the middle of the input and reject the whole input outright, something *else* from which `scanf` doesn't protect you.

Answer (score 0):

Simple read 1 `char` and test it.

```
int ch;
while ((ch = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF) {
  if ((ch < '1') || (ch > '5')) {
    fputs(stdout, "That's a not number 1 to 5.\n");
  }
  else {
    ch -= '0';
    printf("Good: %d entered\n", ch);
  }
}
```